# Installer cannot see SSD

Tags: system-installation, ssd

Trying to breath some life into an old Toshiba Satellite Pro A105, I installed a compatible SSD (actually MSATA and an adapter).  The BIOS can see it no problem, but the Linux installer did not.

Fdisk -l does not show the drive.

GPARTED does not see the drive.

Just to see what would happen, I used the recovery disc that came with the computer and installed Windows XP without even needing a driver!  Thinking the Ubuntu installer might be able to see it now that it was formatted, I tried again with no luck.

The BIOS is old, and has NO options for setting a drive mode (IDE, AHCI, RAID).

Am I SOL?

EDIT: Requested Information: gparted starts off with "Invalid partition table - recursive partition on /dev/sr0," but that's the DVD; in the devices menu it only shows /dev/sr0, the other drive is not listed.

Hardware: Intel Core Duo T2400, Intel 945GM Express chipset, 2GB RAM, SATA-150 (although, keep in mind, the BIOS and Windows XP can both see this drive).

The new drive is a Kingspec 64GB mSATA, model number ACSC2M064mSA, with a fairly generic mSATA to SATA connector.

Comment: What does GParted show? And Hardware specs?

Comment: Sorry; was out of town, but I edited the question with more details.

Comment: GParted has a drop down menu. Are you sure the DVD is the only drive listed?

Comment: Yes, it's the only drive listed.